# Power BI - Matrix with limited number of columns

Tags: powerbi

I am currently using a matrix in Power BI to display my data. Everything works perfectly except the fact, that the matrix just shows a limited number of columns.
Do you know how to change the max. number or is there another trick how to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The limitation is for 100 columns only as of October 2020.  One option is to export the data using the export option into Excel, then convert it to cross-tab (matrix) report.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Matrix has the limitation on displaying the number of columns and unfortunately we cant change this limitation. You can consider some custom visuals to achieve the same result.

Comment: FYI - Other visuals ( Like chart) doesn't have the same limitation.